# String operation in array

Tags: android, arrays

how to resolve this error  **`The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) String[][], String`**

```
  SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
   String [][]str = null;  

    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";
```

Comment: What you want to do with this code..?? so we can examine what type of solution is preferred to you...

Answer (score 2):

The error pretty much says it all - you can't use `+=` with an array in Java. Why not use a List to build up the String values and then convert it into an array when you are finished?

```
    List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();  

    for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
        str.add("SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress());                     
        str.add(" :");
        ...

    String[] strArray = str.toArray(new String[str.size()]);
```

Comment: how i add  this line  in this code

 str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

Comment: so u mean i used  in the end   strarray to pass as a parameter instead of  str  like 

ntent l = new Intent(context,AgAppMenu.class);
                 //    l.putExtra("msg",str);
                     Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();

                     mBundle.putSerializable("msg",str);


ntent l = new Intent(context,AgAppMenu.class);
                 //    l.putExtra("msg",str);
                     Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();

                     mBundle.putSerializable("msg",strArray);

Comment: i want  final   resulr  String[] strArray in  2 dimentional array 

String[][] strArray

Comment: There was a option to pass String array to bundle.
You please declare str as Single Array.
and pass it as

l.putStringArray("key", str);

Comment: acctully i have and already build application  which used 2 dimentional response from http server and perform action   i just modify that application to use sms service is not internet available so i do not want to change code
just pass resive sms response in 2 dimentional array to that activity
which used response in this statement 
if (xmlRespone[0][0] == null